# Browser Page looks messy

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

To develop websites I use domino designer v9.01 with OpenNTF Bootstrap extension library v14. I am new to IBM domino so have mercy …
The trouble I have is : While previewing XPage apps in Notes all controls, views etc. are there and looks as expected. But when I preview same XPage apps in a web browser (newest FireFox, newest Microsoft Edge) I get messy results. To be more specific, the amount of controls, views, etc. are there and they also work. But their expected design is messy. I cannot describe it better because I have never seen such pages before.

Finally the question is : Why is the presentation of XPage apps in Notes perfect while in a web browser not ?

UPDATE

Here are 2 screenshots to visualize the problem. First screenshot is from Notes showing expected UI. Second screenshot is from FireFox browser showing non-expected UI which i call "messy". The content you see is a simple example from a tutorial. So do not wonder about that.

[image: Notes screenshot]

[image: FireFox screenshot]

Comment: Is this using local web preview? Local web preview does not pick up the OSGi plugins from the same location installed in Domino Designer. This may prompt someone to confirm the setup required for local web preview.

Comment: For development purposes I use domino server and designer in one domain on my computer. When I initiate within the designer "preview with web browser" then I guess I use also local web prewiew. What do you mean with "This may prompt someone to confirm the setup required for local web preview" ?

Comment: Thanks, if it's Domino server then it's more straightforward. For previewing on web from Domino Designer when you're not using a server, I think the plugins need to be added to an additional location, but I can't remember what it is. But that's not going to be relevant in your scenario, because you're previewing the application on a server.

Comment: Please add a picture so that we can see what "messy" looks like? Also, check your browser's developer tools and check for 404 to see if CSS resources load as expected.

Comment: @PaulStephenWithers The plugins from the update site, if you're going to add them manually into DDE, would need to go into `C:[Notes-install]\Data\domino\workspace\applications\eclipse\plugins`.

Comment: added 2 screenshots to show what I call messy

Answer (score 0):

The Extension Library plugin will also need to be installed on the server as well as into Domino Designer. The usual process for this is using an UpdateSite database, as documented here http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=XPages+Extensibility+API#action=openDocument&res_title=XPages_Extension_Library_Deployment&content=apicontent

Comment: To install ExtensionLibraryOpenNTF-901v00...    I followed this link http://tlcc.com/admin/tlccsite.nsf/pages/extension-lib.  What is the difference between this and your recommendation ?

Comment: That looks to be for installing for use in local databases, not in databases on a full Domino server.

Comment: Sorry know it's getting confusing for me. As I wrote above in an answer I use a domino server and designer installation on my computer in one domain (locally). The webbrowser makes "localhost" calls. So I guess I use a local database. Or what are you calling a "local database" ?  Anyway what is the problem I have with browser UI (see added screenshots)?

Comment: Is the database in a folder relative to the Notes & Designer Client install (by default Program Files\Notes\Data) or relative to a Domino server (by default Program Files\Domino\Data). If the first one, it's a local database, local to the Notes Client, and the using local preview, so TLCC's setup is required. If the second, it's a server-based database (even though it's on your local PC), and the Extension Library should also be added to the server's UpdateSite.nsf, following the steps in the link I posted. localhost could point to Domino server's nhttp or Designer Client's nhttp

Comment: Wherever it is, all that's available to the browser is the base Extension Library, not the v14 installed into Designer, because it's not picking up the bootstrap renderers / stylesheets.

Comment: Thanks so far for your help. But this is going beyond my current knowledge concering installing an IBM domino system. I thought its a minor problem of installing an extension lib. I see I have to consult an admin for this. When I am updated I come back.