# XPage does not render Bootstrap Theme

Tags: xpages

After making a new Domino Designer installation (newest version) and a complete fresh ExtensionLibraryOpenNTF-901v00_15 … updateSite installation bootstrap is not rendered in XPage for browser preview.

I can switch to `Bootstrap3.2.0` Theme in XPage Properties and I can even see the proper layout in Notes preview - but not in the browser preview. When I view the browser source code I do not see any `bootstrap` loaded.

What do I miss ?

browser head source code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">if(!navigator.cookieEnabled)window.location.href="http://localhost:8080/TC_Antrag.nsf/xpLogin.xsp?SessionID=794A663A0EF7B90C0BCED10E0EE4C3691ACFABE0";</script>
<title>CERES TC Portal</title>
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/TC_Antrag.nsf/favicon.ico">
<script type="text/javascript">var dojoConfig = {locale: 'en-gb', parseOnLoad: true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/dojoroot-1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.registerModulePath("extlib", "/xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib");</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/xsp/.ibmxspres/.mini/dojo/.en-gb/@Fz&amp;@Ec.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("ibm.xsp.widget.layout.xspClientDojo")</script>
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dojo.parser")</script>
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox")</script>
<script type="text/javascript">dojo.require("extlib.dijit.Dialog")</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browser Page looks messy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33236936/browser-page-looks-messy)

Comment: partly - In that thread everything was running in a virtual box and finally after a new installation bootstrap was rendered perfect. Now the installation is on a new PC and all the recommendation in that thread I followed here, but there is no bootstrap theme recognizeable. Quite complicated ...

Comment: Is it local preview or previewing an NSF on a server? Both are covered in that question. Previewing a local NSF requires copying plugin files

Comment: local previewing but without any server

Comment: See Eric McCormick's comment on that other question

Comment: I've also covered OSGi plugins and the local web preview in the slidedeck on the homepage of bootstrap4xpages.com (slide 18).

Comment: The answer lies in then comment of Paul Stephen Withers linking to Eric McCormick's comment. How to vote ?

Comment: You could add the answer yourself, and select that answer as the "accepted answer"